# Adding searchBar to tableHeaderView adds bottom empty space

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I need to add `UISearchController` to `UIViewController` I know that the best way to do it is adding it to `UINavigationController` like this:

```
    let resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: athkarSearchTable)
    resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = athkarSearchTable

    navigationItem.searchController = resultSearchController
```

The problem is I can't use `UINavigationController` so I found another solution: adding it to `tableHeaderView` like the following:

```
let resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: athkarSearchTable)

        controller.searchResultsUpdater = athkarSearchTable
        // to give a semi-transparent background when the search bar is selected.
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal

        tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
        
        return controller
    })()
    // to limit the overlap area to just the View Controller’s frame instead of the whole Navigation Controller
        definesPresentationContext = true
```

However, this solution adds an empty space to the bottom of the `tableView` in the `UIViewController` not the `athkarSearchTable` which is not good :/ as the screenshot below:

[image]

I tried to set the footer to an empty view and to set the height of footer to zero, none of them worked :/

Any suggestion how to remove the bottom empty space?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding the following lines:

```
tableView.rowHeight          = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400
```